# How to multiply inputs in Tensorflow inside the Neural Network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, data-science

How do I multiply my features inside a Neural Network (not before)?
I am trying to do so with the code below. When running the code I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense_38 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full shape received: (1,)
```

It is expecting a two-dimensional input, I do not understand why.

```
def multiply(x):
    return tf.math.multiply(x=x[0, :], y= x[1, :])

inputs = Input(shape=(2, )) 
r= Dense(units=1, activation=multiply)(inputs) 
fr = Dense(units=1, activation='relu', )(r) ...
```

Comment: Use `tf.keras.layers.Lambda()` as a layer you want to modify your data in the middle of your model. Note that because it will be executed on the graph mode, you can not use tensor slicing like that, and you need to use tensorflow built-in functions such as `tf.slice()`

Comment: Yes, it works with tf.slice, thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of the community, I am adding the **@Kaveh** answer here in answer section. 
(Thank you **@Kaveh** and **@user26616** for the confirmation)

> Use tf.keras.layers.Lambda() as a layer you want to modify your data
> in the middle of your model. Note that because it will be executed on
> the graph mode, you cannot use tensor slicing like that, and you need
> to use tensorflow built-in functions such as tf.slice().